# Unresolved externals in c++ program

Tags: c++

So I have been given some c++ code by my project manager to complete. The code had certain parts of it missing which I was required to fill in. As you can see below this is what I am left with after completing the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct Cars {
  char Name[20]; 
  unsigned int Wheel; 
  double Speed; 
};

#define database_size 10
#define database_filename "cars.txt"

void enter(Cars&, unsigned long);

int main()
{
  Cars Car[database_size];  
  unsigned long database_length = 0; 

  char UserInput;

  while (1) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Cars database" << endl;
    cout << "1. Enter a new car model" << endl;
    cout << "6. Exit the program" << endl << endl;



    cout << "Please pick a number: ";
    cin >> UserInput;
    cout << endl;


    switch(UserInput) {
      case '1':
        enter(Car[database_length], database_length);
        break;

      case '6':
        return 0;

      default:
        cout << "Invalid entry" << endl << endl;
        break;
    }
  }
}

void enter(Cars& unsigned long)
{  
    if (Cars == DATABASE_MAX)
    {
        cout << "Unfortunately the database is full ";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "database not full";    
    }
}
```

Now the issue i'm having is that, whenever I compile it gives me the unresolved externals error and unresolved symbol error as well. I had a look online and most of the answers are related to something called a "link time" error? but i'm not quite sure if that applies here as well or not.

Any ideas would be appreicated.

Edit: Currently recieving the following error: "error C2513: 'OpAmps' : no variable declared before '='"
Could that be related to me using the wrong type of if?

Comment: I do not think teacher is the same as "project manager"

Comment: @Slava Unrelated to my question.... not sure how you are helping here.

Comment: you either lie about "project manager" or work for very strange company

Comment: @Slava unrelated to my question once again... And it's not a company just incase this will make a difference to the code...

Comment: @Slava probably just a language difficulty ..

Comment: @ramo55 why you call your teacher "project manager" then? cause it looks you try to misinform people so they would not think this is homework  for a school. This looks fishy.

Comment: @Slava At least he deserves an answer for the cleverness.

Comment: @c-smile even if it is homework he would deserve an answer as he shows enough effort. But I do not like when people cheat.

Comment: @Slava did you consider that it actually is his project manager? Why do you insist so much that he is cheating when there is no clear evidence other than a question that looks similar to homework?

Comment: @Slava tempted to ignore you if i'm honest, people like you ruin the community here. If you must know, this is part of a special needs organisation where kids learn code to help them out with a possible career in the future, this was part of a project given to me by my project manager. I was tasked with completing the code for an upcoming demenstrations for the kids.

Comment: @tobi303 My appologies indeed for not clarifiying, It just seemed as something completely unrelated but I guess I am also knew to the community here.

Comment: @ramo55 I said it looks fishy, I did not say you are cheating. You could just clarify. I apologize for overreaction, there are too many pupils here who jsut want their homework to be done without effort.

Comment: @Slava No worries, I appreciate your concern, however that's not the case here.

Comment: I deleted my comment, because I didnt want to add more spam. However, now that you replied to it, let me make my point again: you could have avoided this overreaction by stating from the beginning this background information. It happens quite often that OPs are trying to hide information when there is no need to do so. In such cases it really can be annoying when you try to help but get answer along the line "i will not tell you because it is not related". However, I think the issues is resolved now and everybody is happy ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "link time" error.  Your declaration for `enter`'s parameters...

```
void enter(Cars&, unsigned long);
```

don't match your implementation for `enter`'s parameters:

```
void enter(unsigned long Cars)
```

You need an implementation for `enter` that matches the way you're using it (with both a reference to `Cars` and an `unsigned long`).  Since your compiler sees you declared it and used it without implementing it the "unresolved externals" is the compiler's way of saying it can't find it.

### Post Edit

You now have several new issues between your declaration and implementation:

1) The decalaration says you have two variables, one of type `Cars&` and one of type `unsigned long`:

```
void enter(Cars&, unsigned long);
```

Your implementation doesn't have the comma or variable names (the declaration only needs the types but the implementation also needs the names so you can use them).  Instead of `void enter(Cars& unsigned long)` you should have...

```
void enter(Cars& arg_cars, unsigned long arg_number) {...}
```

where `arg_cars` and `arg_number` are the names of the two variables.

2) You want to change the first line in the function to check the number you're passing in:

```
if (arg_number == DATABASE_MAX) { ... }
```

3) You don't define `DATABASE_MAX` anywhere.

Comment: Hi there, So I changed them so they now match, and I just recieved a new error: "error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)"

Comment: @ramo55 I'm guessing you have a ; somewhere that you shouldn't.

Comment: no I don't think that's the problem. I changed the code so now it's "void enter(Cars& unsigned long)" but that throws in another error about "No variable declared before '='"

Comment: @ramo55 maybe you should update your question with the current code so we know what it currently looks like?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah My appologies, code has been updated now.

Comment: @ramo55  Updated my answer.

Comment: @ramo55  Change questions only if it will not invalidate correct answers or move the question's goalposts. If the answer to the problem exposes more problems, debug them or ask new questions.

Comment: @GuntherFox Thanks for the comments, I shall relook into my code.